# Firebase data to Google BigQuery

Tags: json, firebase, google-bigquery

Firebase offers [private backups on Google Cloud Storage](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-05-private-backups-for-firebase-data.html). One of the featured use case is "Ingestion into Analytics Products":

```
Private Backups provides a perfect pipeline into cloud analytics products such as Google’s BigQuery. Cloud Analytics products often prefer to ingest data through Cloud Storage buckets rather than directly from the application.
```

I have a lot of data in Firebase (more than 1GB when exported to a Cloud Storage bucket) and, as described in Firebase offering, I wanted to put those data in Big Query.

But is it really possible to write a table schema that fits Firebase raw data?
Let's take as an example the [dinosaur-facts](https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/) database from Firebase documentation.
The JSON looks like this:

```js
{
  "dinosaurs" : {
    "bruhathkayosaurus" : {
      "appeared" : -70000000,
      "height" : 25
    },
    "lambeosaurus" : {
      "appeared" : -76000000,
      "height" : 2.1
    }
  },
  "scores" : {
    "bruhathkayosaurus" : 55,
    "lambeosaurus" : 21
  }
}
```

To list all dinosaurs, I suppose the only way would be to use a RECORD field in bigQuery schema. But usually RECORDS in BigQuery correspond to an array in the imported JSON. And there's no array here in Firebase, just an object with dinosaur names as the key names.

So a BigQuery table schema like this doesn't work:

```
[
    {
        "name": "dinosaurs",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "dinosaur",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "appeared",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "height",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "length",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "order",
                        "type": "STRING"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "vanished",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "weight",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "scores",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "dinosaur",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is it possible to write a table schema that fits Firebase raw data? Or should we first prepare the data to make it compatible with BigQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Since the data above is just JSON, you should be able to get it to work with Firebase. However, I think that it would be much easier to prepare the data **after the backup**.

You mentioned that there was no arrays in the Firebase data. [Firebase does support arrays, but they have to meet a certain criteria.](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

```
// we send this
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}
// since the keys are numeric and sequential,
// if we query the data, we get this
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Even though it may look like an object in the Firebase database, it will come back as an array when queried.

So it is feasible to create your schema in your Firebase database, but it would likely create a lot of overhead for your application.

Comment: Thank you. I know Firebase support arrays. I was just referring to the data in the dinosaur-facts database. 
Instead of dinosaurs, I have many user profiles stored in Firebase. I thought, based on the description in Firebase blog post, that after upgrading to the Bonfire plan, it would be very easy to do some stats with BigQuery. But in fact it will require a lot of work to prepare the data.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying! Just wanted to make sure you knew how it would be exported. Let me know what you end up doing or if you have any other questions :)

Comment: One thing you could do, is send data to BigQuery as the data is entered into Firebase. This would require you to run a server the supports the Firebase SDK like Node.js or the JVM client. You should be able to run the BigQuery and Firebase SDKs on AppEngine using Java. The server would just listen for updates and send them to BigQuery. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart

Comment: For now on, I think I'll simply ask for a refund on the Bonfire plan. It should be better explained that putting your Firebase data in BigQuery isn't an easy task.

Comment: Creating a script to import the data to BigQuery shouldn't be too difficult. What is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: If I understand well, this script should get from the bucket my daily 1.35GB JSON backup of Firebase data, parse it, read it and create a new file that would then be imported into BigQuery?

Comment: Guys, as of today what would be the best/recommended way (and easiest) to visualize Firebase Realtime DB data into BigQuery ? I just need to create some basic reporting.

Answer (score 3):

When writing this 03/2017, I can confirm that there's no real integration between Firebase Realtime database and BigQuery. Only Firebase Analytics can be imported easily into BigQuery. All this is not clearly explained on Firebase either...

We ended up writing our own solution, but you can check out this [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/bigquery-import) that has some 400+ stars, so I am assuming a few people found it useful...

Answer (score 2):

In fact Big Query only support newline-delimited JSON or JSONL:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery

http://jsonlines.org/

> JSON Lines is a convenient format for storing structured data that may
>   be processed one record at a time.

To prepare Firebase data for import in Big Query, we just need to:

1. Get the JSON from Firebase (or from a Cloud Storage bucket in case of private backup)
2. Parse it to get a JS object
3. Loop through each record, stringify data and add a line separator

   ```
       var dataForBigQuery = '';
       for (var i in dinosaurs) {
         dataForBigQuery+= JSON.stringify(dinosaurs[i]) + '\n';
       }
   ```
4. Save those data in a new file. It will then be ready for import into BigQuery.