# Querying the firestore database from bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to query the firestore database from bigquery without exporting the firestore data into bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery can only query data that is stored in BigQuery itself. It cannot query data directly in Cloud Firestore.

You will have to import the data from Cloud Firestore into BigQuery in order to be able to query it with BigQuery.

Comment: regarding import, can i know steps to do it from both firestore or real time db from firebase

Comment: For Firestore, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore

Comment: For Realtime Database the process seems a bit more involved. A quick search gives results like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332239/firebase-data-to-google-bigquery